# Vue + JQ Ajax Передача параметров

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Почему я не могу присвоить значение переменной showModal , внутри ajax функции ? this.showModal = true; - показывает popup окно. Как сделать правильно ? Пример кода:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'url',
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    action: "send",
    phone : this.tel
  },
  dataType:'JSON',
  success: function (response) {

    if (response.id) {
        this.showModal = true;
    } else {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(response);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

конструкция function изменяет контекст(this) : тоисть внутри функции this ссылается на другой объект.
решение №1: простое решение это стрелочная функция

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'url',
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    action: "send",
    phone : this.tel
  },
  dataType:'JSON',
  success: (response)=>{

    if (response.id) {
        this.showModal = true;
    } else {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(response);
    }
  }
});
```

решение №2: создать ссылку на нужный объект this в области выше видимости, и потом применять эту ссылку

```
var _this = this;
$.ajax({
  url: 'url',
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    action: "send",
    phone : this.tel
  },
  dataType:'JSON',
  success: function (response) {

    if (response.id) {
        _this.showModal = true;
    } else {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(response);
    }
  }
});
```

решение №3: тру программисты может так и делают, но я так не люблю делать, очень стрёмно

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'url',
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    action: "send",
    phone : this.tel
  },
  dataType:'JSON',
  success: (function (response) {

    if (response.id) {
        this.showModal = true;
    } else {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(response);
    }
  }).bind(this)
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ и объяснение